# How to process 2 files with different inputformats in Hadoop Streaming?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have 2 files in different formats. One is `SequenceFileInputFormat`, other one is `TextInputFormat`. I know that for Hadoop Streaming there is a possibility to specify 2 input files like:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming-2.8.0.jar \
  -input '/user/foo/dir1' -input '/user/foo/dir2' \
    (rest of the command)
```

But how to specify also different `-inputformat` for those files?

I found that it's possible to do for Java with `MultipleInputs` like:

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]), <Input_Format_Class_1>);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]), <Input_Format_Class_2>);
```

Can I do somethink like this with Hadoop Streaming?

Answer (score 0):

[Hadoop Streaming Options](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html#Streaming+Command+Options) contains various options for hadoop streaming, the one that might be of use in your case would be

```
-inputformat JavaClassName
```

The Default being TextInputFormat

I have tested this using only TextInputFormat, but i recon it should be like

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming-2.8.0.jar \
  -input '/user/foo/dir1' -inputformat TextInputFormat \
  -input '/user/foo/dir2' -inputformat SequenceFileInputFormat \
    (rest of the command)
```

Here is what is tested and it worked :

```
    hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0*.jar \
      -file mapperB.py -mapper mapperB.py -file reducerB.py -reducer reducerB.py \
      -input /tempfiles/big.txt -inputformat TextInputFormat \
      -input /tempfiles/t.txt -inputformat TextInputFormat \
      -output /tempfiles/output-X
```

Note: `file` is deprecated,